# How do giants play ping pong?

Tags: science-fiction, physics, mythical-creatures, sports

Imagine a tall giant standing at 20m tall weights 40 metric tonnes, they have been watching us playing table tennis and were hoping that one day they could play too. How do I design a giant ping pong ball for these giants? What material would the ball be made of?

Comment: A ping pong is called table tennis. And the ping-pong ball is not the same material as tennis ball. So any ball that is scalled to fit 20 metres giants. Yoga ball?

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY he's calling it table tennis isn't he? I think it's not really possible, unless you add weight in some way. A beach ball loses all momentum and flies away easily, as the friction of the ball vs the energy (weight) of the ball is simply too much of a difference. In short, the square cube law would fuck it up. But maybe someone here corrects me and says a ball that size you can just make it of iron or carbon nanotubes or something and it'll work fine.

Comment: Said giants are already violating physics by existing if they have human proportions, so I wouldn't be too concerned about it from a narrative perspective.

Comment: I imagine they would play it with a basketball and a giant table.

Comment: If they've been watching tiny people play table tennis, then their visual acuity is sufficient to use tiny people pingpong balls & tables.

Comment: @elemtilas - but not their fine muscle control. I can watch table tennis on my phone  but I couldn't play at that scale.

Comment: Where do the giants live? What is the force of gravity acting on their bodies? How thick is the atmosphere?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the same synthetic rubber, fabric, and wire combination used in vehicle tires. It needs to bear its own weight without breaking on impact, have the necessary elasticity to create a satisfactory bounce, and enough mass to overcome wind resistance at the larger size so you can achieve a solid forward trajectory after each hit. Something too bouncy (like dodgeballs) would be utter chaos.

Equally large (ha ha) problems would include the size and composition of the table and paddles...